# Android - referencing string array using another string to avoid using SQLite

Tags: android, string, reference

I've searched for this but I'm not exactly sure what I should be searching for.

I'm trying to avoid using a SQLite DB and was wondering is it possible to call a string using the value of another string.

Eg.

If I have in a xml file this:

```
    <string-array name="bob">
<item>1</item>
<item>4</item>
<item>7</item>
<item>11</item>
</string-array>
```

And in a Java file this:

```
String name = "bob";
```

can I then do something like this:

```
String[] holder = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess correctly what you are needing is [getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Take into account that this method is expensive and it is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've spent a while on Google and come up with this:  `int holderint = getResources().getIdentifier("name", "array", this.getPackageName());`  
       `String[] holder= getResources().getStringArray(holderint);`
       
But it hasn't worked.  The program just crashes when starting.  Any idea on how to fix the syntax.